# How do I keep strings with numeric contents from being interpolated as numeric expressions for JavaScript in ERb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm passing an array from my Rails app to Javascript via a js.erb template. The thing that's killing me is trying to keep numeric strings from being interpolated as numeric expressions. I have a set of dates correlated with numbers, i.e.:

```
[["2010-12-01", 19], ["2010-12-02", 12], ["2010-12-03", 15], ["2010-12-04", 0], ["2010-12-05", 0], ["2010-12-06", 13], ["2010-12-07", 18]]
```

So, to get that into a JS array I do this:

```
var accData = new Array;
<%- @accepted.each do |ary| %>
  accData.push([Date.parse(<%= ary[0] %>), parseInt(<%= ary[1].count %>) ]);
<%- end %>
```

But when I check the value of `ary[0]` in the JS console, I get `1997`, i.e., `2010 - 12 - 01`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<%= ary[0] %>` statement inside a pair of quotes, since `<%=` doesn't surround the `2010-12-01` in them. You also don't actually need parseInt either (unless you surround the `ary[1].count` call in quotes too):

```
var accData = new Array;
<%- @accepted.each do |ary| %>
  accData.push([Date.parse("<%= ary[0] %>"), <%= ary[1].count %> ]);
<%- end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this is to use the `inspect` method to produce a properly enquoted string you can use in the JavaScript itself:

```
var accData = new Array;
<%- @accepted.each do |ary| %>
  accData.push([Date.parse(<%= ary[0].inspect %>), <%= ary[1].count.inspect %> ]);
<%- end %>
```

You can also make use of the `to_json` method which will often return something very JavaScript friendly and handles `nil` to `null` conversion, among other things.